# pass multiple variables to lambda functions in how= in resample()

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, group-by, resampling

I have a dataframe with 7 million rows of temperature spreads of daily data between approximately 6000 cities with index = daily date.

```
col_1 = City2 - City1 (sum of temp spread day hours 6am - 9pm)
col_2 = City2 - City1 (sum of temp spread night hours 10pm-6am)
```

I want to compute:

```
positive_spread_sum = sum(City2-City1, where City2-City1 > 0)
negative_spread_sum = sum(City2-CIty1, where City2-CIty1 < 0)
```

I do this as follows:

```
pos_sum = df.groupby(['city1', 'city2']).resample('M', how={'col_1':lambda x: x[x>0].sum()})

neg_sum = df.groupby(['city1', 'city2']).resample('M', how={'col_2':lambda x: x[x<0].sum()})
```

The problem is I'm collapsing/aggregating the same dataframe multiple times as I iterate through the dataframe. Each collapse/aggregation takes 0.019 seconds which results in 37x2=74 hours of execution time.

This is inefficient.

Is there anyway I can perform ONE collapse/agg/groupby and calculate multiple statistics by passing in multiple variables to the lambda function?

```
lambda x,y: x[x>0].sum(), y[y<0].sum()
```

UPDATE:

I was able to do this in one groupby like so:

```
    pos_neg_sum = df.groupby(['city1', 'city2']).resample('M', how={'col_1': lambda x: x[x>0].sum(),
'col_2': lambda y: y[y>0].sum()})
```

I passed multiple dict functions to how=.

Is this the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: [Help us help you](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - provide a sample input data (5-10 rows) and expected output

Comment: did you check already: `df.groupby([...]).agg({'col1': 'sum', 'col2': 'sum'})`? It's difficult to say what you really need not being able to see a sample data set and expected output, though